# UINavigationController is not always pushing an item?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image: navigation bar]

I pushing view form my first view to second view. When second view appear then navigation bar seem like above image. In this image  i have a button which title is "List". When i click on list button then appear third view. for that i have used this code...

```
 -(IBAction)list{
place_Object=[[Places alloc] initWithNibName:@"Places" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:place_Object animated:YES];
[place_Object release];
//self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

}

Now problem is when click on list button then sometime view appear and sometime view not push by navigation and giving any error. What is error in this code or what is mistake so that it occur.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Put a log statement in your method above. Is the problem that the method is not being called (in which case your problem is elsewhere). The code you have posted looks fine.

Comment: @jrturton i have three view first second third. I navigate from first to second and second to third and third to first  and again first to second and now when go to third by click on list button then problem occur.

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question to include the part where you set up the right bar button item, or do you do it in interface builder? Also, have you done the logging as I suggested, and what was the result?

Comment: Style tip: Common convention in Objective-C is to camelCase your variables without intervening under_scores. In code you encounter out there in the world, your variable place_Object is more likely to be spelled "placeObject".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the VIEW appear first time when you puhs BUTTON list and after that you receive error, mayby is from this **[place_Object release];**. You have to release in -(void)dealloc otherwise you call zombie. Try to research with Instruments. Use Run/Run With Performance Tool/Allocations there just Enable Zombie and see what happen.
Hope this help you.

Comment: what you mean how use zombie? How use zombie in Allocations with Instruments or what is to call zombie?

Answer (score 0):

place_object is an instance of PLACE?

if place_object was declared as this:

```
PLACE *place_object;
```

You should not release it inside your -(IBAction)list. Try to remove [place release] from -(IBAction)list and add it in your -(void)dealloc function